when I use onSubmit in the form then the whole ui disappear
my code is working fine but when I use onSubmit in the form as attribute then the whole UI disappear and nothing is shown on the UI why?
What is the solution please ?
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> // what is the problem with this line because this onsubmitdisappear the ui 
// the code goes here
</form>


please share the whole file code and specifically  handle submit function + form

It sounds like there might be an issue with the handleSubmit function. Make sure it's defined correctly like this:
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}

There might be error in your console.
please share your code/error from console or create a sample on CodeSandbox (or a similar site)

Are you using the preventDefault() method inside your handleSubmit function?
The <form ...> default behavior is to submit and refresh the page, which is why the UI disappears. You need to handle it by preventing this default behavior with preventDefault(). By calling preventDefault() inside handleSubmit, you prevent the form from submitting and refreshing the page, allowing you to handle the form data as needed.
Here is how you should modify your handleSubmit function:
const handleSubmit = (submitevent) => {
submitevent.preventDefault();
// form submission logic here
//...

}


Use event.preventDefault(); as following:
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...rest of your code
}

And invoke the function with the "event" parameter (optional, actually works fine even without this)
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(event)}> 
 // what is the problem with this line because this onsubmitdisappear the UI 
 // the code goes here
</form>

Summary:

event.preventDefault();

is going to stop the default action of an element from happening and fix this issue.
This stops all of the default behavior that would normally occur when submitting a form. The code is what you actually want to happen when submitting.


As you haven't mentioned any source code, these might be the issues you are facing:

Proper initialization of the function.
If it's redirecting to a blank page, you should prevent the default behavior of form submission, as shown in the code below.

function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   
</form>


